# Unable to load DLL 'SqlServerSpatial.dll'

Tags: .net, sql-server, azure

I have a .NET MVC web application referencing `System.Data.Spatial` so I can use the `DbGeography` datatype on a property for some geolocation stuff. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with .NET 4.5 and do not have a full installation of SQL Server on my development machine (only localdb).

The app works great until I push it to Azure. As soon as my app hits my `DbGeography` property, it throws this error:

> Unable to load DLL 'SqlServerSpatial.dll': The specified module could
>   not be found.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

SqlServerSpatial.dll is unmanaged code. You have to install the correct version (64bit) on the server. Add the DLL to your project. Set the properties of SqlServerSpatial110.dll to “Copy to Output directory = Copy always”

You find detailed Information [here](http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/spatial-applications-in-windows-azure-redux-including-denali/)

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to add a reference to the DLL, but as unmanaged code, that obviously doesn't work. I created a Lib directory in my project and stuck the file in there.

Comment: @ryanw51 please, help. How do you mean by you created a 'lib' directory in your project, and stuck the file there.

Comment: @kooldave98 Create a new folder an your project, copy the SqlServerSpatial.dll into this folder and deploy it together with your project.

Comment: I'm using TFS Continuous Integration deployment to Azure.
I have added the `SqlServerSpatial.dll` and even `SqlServerSpatial110.dll`. I have checked everything into TFS and a build and deployment has been done. I am still having the same problem.

Comment: @kooldave98 Did you read this? http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/spatial-applications-in-windows-azure-redux-including-denali/

Comment: The blog post is kinda old, but I followed it and I got to the point where it says I needed to add project references to the DLLs. Now this is where I got stuck. VisualStudio doesn't let me add the project complaining that it is inaccessible and invalid

Comment: You can't add references to unmanaged code in a .NET project. Which DLL do you try to reference?

Comment: `SqlServerSpatial.dll`

Comment: the description doesn't say you have to add a reference to SqlServerSpatial.dll. You only have to add it to the project and do copy to output directory. You have to add a reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll.

Comment: I've tried putting SqlSpacialTools.dll in my bin directory, but no dice :(

Comment: @IanGrainger did you reference Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll? Do you use the correct version (32/64bit)?

Comment: @slfan I've got past my error with the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll - now I'm having an error with SqlSpacialTools.dll not found. I've tried Googling and getting the latest and putting it in System32, SysWOW64, and bin folder, but no dice... I'm wondering if I need an older version that's compatible with the original Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll.

Comment: Well I don't have IIS Express checked to run in 64 bit mode, and I have SqlServerSpacial.dll in System32 - and I've copied it to my bin directory. (I was looking for SqlSpacialTools.dll before, which was wrong - but this hasn't helped, either!)

Comment: Got it! I tried _checking_ 64 bit mode and it's worked. I took everyone saying 'make sure you have the right 32/64 bit version' as: get 64 bit, but of course, if IIS Express is 32 bit, I need to install the 32 bit version of the SQL Server 2008 System CLR Types!

Answer (score 3):

SQL 2012 installs this dll too, SQL 2014 don't! You have to install the Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2008 R2 on the machine.

1. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26728
2. Click **Download**
3. **Check off one of these** depending on your processor architecture:

   - 1033\x64\SQLSysClrTypes.msi
   - 1033\x86\SQLSysClrTypes.msi
   - 1033\IA64\SQLSysClrTypes.msi
4. Click **Next**

**Edit**

as `Ian Grainger`'s comment, you have to install the correct version based on your IIS. apparently IIS Express runs in 32bit mode by default.

Comment: I did this and it's made no difference.

Comment: Hi, @Mahmoodvcs - please could you update this answer to mention that it's depending on the architecture of your IIS/IIS Express! I installed the correct one for my architecture (64), but IIS Express runs in 32 bit mode by default!

Comment: Most of this answer's text is taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14797013/11683 without attribution.

Answer (score 3):

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" 
  publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: put the above in app.config file. Change newVersion as needed.

Comment: This solved the problem. Related topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204990/entity-framework-cannot-update-database

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem and was truly missing the SqlServerSpatial110.dll

I ended up following the instructions here:

http://dllyes.com/sqlserverspatial110-dll/

Basically you need to get your hands on that .dll and then

> Place SqlServerSpatial110.dll in \Windows\System32 (usually located at
>   disk C) if you’re running 32 bit Windows. If you’are running 64 bit
>   Windows, additionally place file in \Windows\SysWOW64.

Comment: This worked for me.

I used nuget to download the SqlServerTypes assemblies to my solution but when I ran the EntityFramework command Add-Migration, it couldn't find the SqlServerSpatial140.dll. My IIS is 32bit but my Windows architecture is 64 bit, so I had to copy the 32 bit dll into C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64. If you run the command Add-Migration and get  System.BadImageFormatException, then you have a 64 bit dll when it should be 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with it for a quite some time, i installed required files, but it still wasn't working.

Apparently, the project wanted to use x86 SqlServerSpatial.dll
So i changed the IIS Express Build to x64 in Tools>Options>WebProjects>Use the 64 bit IIS
 [Here is the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ks8PF.png)

There is no need of adding new nuget packages, just install the SQLSysClrTypes from microsoft page : http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188391&clcid=0x409   and it should be fine ;)

Hope that it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your dlls(such as "sqlserverspatial110.dll" , "sqlserverspatial120.dll" , ..) be in this path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64";

Answer (score 0):

If the files are referenced in the project correctly and added to source control and the issue is still occurring, try installing the Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server on the machine it's failing on.

-Install the version matching the **SqlServerTypes** referenced in the project.

-Install either the 64 bit or 32 bit of **SQLSysClrTypes.msi** matching what the project is or 'msbuild' platform the compile script is using. This doesn't require the full version of SQL Server to be installed on the machine.

```
Version | Assembly
2005    | 9.0.0.0
2008    | 10.0.0.0
2008 R2 | 10.0.0.0
2012    | 11.0.0.0
2014    | 12.0.0.0
2016    | 13.0.0.0
2017    | 14.0.0.0
2019    | 15.0.0.0
2022    | 16.0.0.0
```

Answer (score -1):

- `SqlGeometry` and `SqlGeography` types can be used in VS projects (e.g.
  C#) by referencing the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll`.
- `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll` is a managed library and has some
  unmanaged library as prerequisites and they are like
  `SqlServerSpatialXXX.dll` and `msvcrXXX.dll`
- Since Sql Server 2008, different versions of
  `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll` are available, however, I don't see any
  functionality change from 2012 on.

For a detailed solution you may want to see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40880753/1468295) on another similar post.

Answer (score -1):

```
I had the same issue in godaddy VPS with windows server 2012 r2
```

> I Resolved it by Updating my EF5 to EF6

in package manager console run to EF5 to EF lalest

```
Install-Package EntityFramework
```