# SqlServerSpatial110.dll failed to copy on Windows Azure deployment

Tags: .net, sql-server, windows, azure, cloud

I have an exsting which is deployed on Windows Azure. But the deployment has been failed with following error. How to fix his

```
Copying file SqlServerTypes\x64\SqlServerSpatial110.dll to C:\DWASFiles\Sites\<project>\Temp\b3d105f6-8fd0-4093-9957-8174422abded\SqlServerTypes\x64\SqlServerSpatial110.dll failed. Could not find file 'SqlServerTypes\x64\SqlServerSpatial110.dll'.
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to load DLL 'SqlServerSpatial.dll'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868326/unable-to-load-dll-sqlserverspatial-dll)

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem recently and found this blog post that solved it for me: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/12/09/microsoft-sqlserver-types-nuget-package-spatial-on-azure.aspx

Effectively the solution is to add a NuGet package called `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` to your project. This package comes with a readme that explains what you need to do and it's very straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Installing NuGet package `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` solved the problem.
But remember also to add this line before calling any spatial operation:

```
SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

This is explained inside `readme.htm` after installing NuGet package.