# How to use SqlServer.Types / spatial types within ASP.NET Core 1.0 application

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

One of our class libraries uses the Microsoft spatial types like DbGeography. When running our application on a clean machine without older versions of SQL Server and Visual Studio, we get this exception:

> Spatial types and functions are not available for this provider 
>       because the assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' version 10 
>       or higher could not be found.

The solution is apparently to install this nuget package:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
```

After installing, the nuget package gives instructions on how to reference the DLLs from each project type:

> To deploy an application that uses spatial data types to a machine that does not have 'System CLR Types for SQL Server' installed you also need to deploy the native assembly SqlServerSpatial110.dll.
>
> Both x86 (32 bit) and x64 (64 bit) versions of this assembly have been added to your project under the SqlServerTypes\x86 and SqlServerTypes\x64 subdirectories. The native assembly msvcr100.dll is also included in case the C++ runtime is not installed.
>
> You need to add code to load the correct one of these assemblies at runtime (depending on the current architecture).
>
> ASP.NET applications
>   For ASP.NET applications, add the following line of code to the Application_Start method in Global.asax.cs: 
>       SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(Server.MapPath("~/bin"));
>
> Desktop applications
>   For desktop applications, add the following line of code to run before any spatial operations are performed: 
>       SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);

The nuget package project site is unresponsive, so I'm not sure this is the best approach to use now in 2016.

My problem is, I can't figure out how to call LoadNativeAssemblies from an ASP.NET Core 1.0 application. **We're using the full framework (net461)** and not the core framework.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        ...
        SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(env.WebRootPath);
        ...
    }
}
```

What is the best way to include the SqlServer.Types dll files within an ASP.NET 1.0 application?

Related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868326/unable-to-load-dll-sqlserverspatial-dll?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887497/sqlserverspatial110-dll-failed-to-copy-on-windows-azure-deployment%5C) on StackOverflow.

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: No progress at all. I'm still hoping to figure it out...

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when you don't include that line? In my .NET Framework project, I didn't need to load the assemblies manually and it worked fine. I haven't managed to run it on .NET Core yet due to other compatibility problems.

Comment: Was this issue resolved? If not was there anything else we can do other than not using .net core.

Answer (score 5):

I got this working on an ASP.NET Core application today (.NET Framework underneath, not .NET Core, same as the original poster).

The thing I noticed is that adding the Nuget package directly to my ASP.NET Core site yielded no additional files. Not sure if the packages were ever updated to work with ASP.NET Core?

At any rate, I just added the package to a traditional .NET Framework 4.x  project and ripped out the SqlServerTypes folder it creates, then put that folder in the root of my ASP.NET Core project. Changed the `Copy to Output Dicrectory` property for all 4 DLLs underneath from `Do not copy` to `Copy Always`, and added the call to the `LoadLibrary()`.

It's worth noting that the 14.x version of the package is actually SQL vNext which is not out, it should have been marked as a pre-release in my mind. I stuck with 13.x since we're using SQL 2016.

Originally I had put this in the Program.cs file, as it didn't have anything to do with the Middleware, ServiceInjection or hosting Configuration setup. But then you have to get the Path to pass in from reflection, which felt ugly. So I put it as the first line of the Startup constructor instead, since from there I can use the HostingEnvironment path.

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(env.ContentRootPath);

    //The normal config as usual down here...
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
}
```

Comment: I've tried this and can even step through the LoadNativeAssemblies to ensure it gets called, but I still get errors when actually using the types through EF stating 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' version 10 or higher could not be found. Did you do anything else?

Comment: You may also need to add `SqlProviderServices.SqlServerTypesAssemblyName = typeof(SqlGeography).Assembly.FullName;` after the `LoadNativeAssemblies` call. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40166192/1727

Comment: I didn't have do that in my case, but I wasn't using Entity Framework, though I realize the original question was tagged with EF, though the post never actually mentioned it. The steps I mentioned were DAL agnostic. Is this relevant in EF6 or EF Core?

Comment: Microsoft.SqlServer.Types doesn't have a Utilities property, and yes I'm using the latest Microsoft.SqlServer.Types nuget package. What am I missing?

Comment: It's not actually a part of the assembly, it's a simple method that the Nuget package adds to your project as a content item when you first add it. Look for the `Loader.cs` file that it should have added as part of the install process for the package.

Comment: If you're still having problems, let me know

Comment: So you didn’t add the SqlServer.Types NuGet package? Just copied the other dlls and loaded them. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct. I don't have a dependency on the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` package any more. I Just copied the files to `<ProjectRoot>/SqlServerTypes`, and load them as the first lines of my Startup

Answer (score 2):

i fix this with a bindingRedirect in web.config file.

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

im using SQL 2016, ASP.NET (no core) and EF 6.0.0.0

Comment: This question is specifically about ASP.NET Core, so your answer is not useful in any way.

Answer (score 0):

this seemed to work for me:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            ...
            SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(env.WebRootPath + @"path to the project that contains the SQLServerTypes folder");
            ...
        }
    }
```

I notice that `IHostingEnvironment.WebRootPath` returns the path that points to the wwwroot however in my solution setup I have multiple projects within that folder, so just telling it which project to point to helped me. Sorry if this doesn't help.

Comment: also while debugging this worked for me `SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/bin"));`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, its not a clean fix, indeed it is everything but clean:

I had to create a folder in /bin named packages with the sql server types package... And I had to do it in every project referenced by the asp net core one that was using sql server types so it seems to be a bug or a missbeheviour in the targets files.

Note that this workaround will have to be done by everyone in your team because /bin content won't be under source control, as it's expected.

I hope it helps (meanwhile it is fixed)

(Well, It's too late, tomorrow I'll think a bit more on what caused the problem and how I fixed it and if I find a better workaround I'll let you know, by know it builds and run as expected)

Answer (score 0):

Using .net core 2.0. After installing the nuget package mentioned above I put this in Program.cs before the line with BuildWebHost(args).Run(); and it worked..

Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
            SqlProviderServices.SqlServerTypesAssemblyName =
                "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91";

Answer (score 0):

Reference to bin directory worked for me :)

```
SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(Server.MapPath("~/bin"));
```