# Microsoft.SqlServer.Types in ASP NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, dll

I'm trying to get the nuget package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types to work in ASP Core targeting full framework 461. I need to use the types SqlGeography and SqlHierarchyId. But when I run my test I get following error *'Unable to load DLL SqlServerSpatial140.dll'*. I know when the package is installed the dlls file can be found in the .nuget\packages\microsoft.sqlserver.types\14.0.314.76\nativeBinaries\ folder.

**But how do I include the dlls in my solution the best way?**

I would like the dlls to be updated when the package is updated. The path can not be hardcode to a specific user path, it has to work on every pc setup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use SqlServer.Types / spatial types within ASP.NET Core 1.0 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38908803/how-to-use-sqlserver-types-spatial-types-within-asp-net-core-1-0-application)

Answer (score 1):

There is a readme.htm file included with the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types Nuget package. It will explain how to load the needed native dll files.
Basically you need to call this line in your code:

```
SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```