# Is Microsoft.SqlServer.Types fully compatible with ASP.NET Core 2.2?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

i'm migrating an ASP.NET server to ASP.NET Core but in a point it threw: Can't access to Microsoft.SqlServer.Types dlls, to solve this i installed Nuget Microsoft.SqlServer.Types and i works fine, but Visual Studio 2019 show a warning:

Warning NU1701  Package 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types 14.0.1016.290' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Comment: Why do you need this library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft.SqlServer.Types incompatible with .NET Standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54448139/11683)

Comment: This basically means the library in question is a non-.NET Core nuget package. There _should_ be a 'Core' version of the package available which might also mean a level of code refactoring to make it work. This of course is all dependant on your existing code though.

Comment: Selvin: I need this library because in my code i have:                                 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {               
                var geoStringList = conn.Query(q, query.TypesReturn, query.ConverterFunction, splitOn: query.splitOn);    ... }

Comment: How did you end up solving this? I am stuck on the same issue...