# Unable to load DLL 'SqlServerSpatial150.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Only on prod)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have no idea why its trying to find v15.0 as I am explicitly trying to tell it to load v14.0. When adding NuGet package, the highest version I see is 14.x.  This works perfectly on my dev machine, but when deployed to prod (win2019/sql server 2019 with CU8) I get the above error.

I only get error when I invoke `GetPointFromLatLong`

```
    static DbGeography GetPointFromLatLong(double lat, double lng)
    {
        return DbGeography.FromText(string.Format("POINT({0} {1})", lng, lat), 4326);
    }


    SqlServerTypes2.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);


namespace SqlServerTypes2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Utility methods related to CLR Types for SQL Server 
    /// </summary>
    public class Utilities
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string libname);

        /// <summary>
        /// Loads the required native assemblies for the current architecture (x86 or x64)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="rootApplicationPath">
        /// Root path of the current application. Use Server.MapPath(".") for ASP.NET applications
        /// and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory for desktop applications.
        /// </param>
        public static void LoadNativeAssemblies(string rootApplicationPath)
        {
            var nativeBinaryPath = IntPtr.Size > 4
                ? Path.Combine(rootApplicationPath, @"SqlServerTypes\x64\")
                : Path.Combine(rootApplicationPath, @"SqlServerTypes\x86\");

            LoadNativeAssembly(nativeBinaryPath, "msvcr120.dll");
            LoadNativeAssembly(nativeBinaryPath, "SqlServerSpatial140.dll");
        }

        private static void LoadNativeAssembly(string nativeBinaryPath, string assemblyName)
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(nativeBinaryPath, assemblyName);
            var ptr = LoadLibrary(path);
            if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format(
                    "Error loading {0} (ErrorCode: {1})",
                    assemblyName,
                    Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you [don't have it installed on the server](https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/spatial-applications-in-windows-azure-redux-including-denali/), since SqlServerSpatial.dll is unmanaged-code.

1. Manually copy/install the *correct* version (64bit) on the server.
2. Then add that DLL to your project.
3. Lastly, select the dll in your references and Set the properties of SqlServerSpatial110.dll to `“Copy to Output directory = Copy always”`

Another option is copy it from the install directory as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42667522/6085193), just make sure your version lines up