# UWP app and SqlServerSpatial140.dll of microsoft.sqlserver.types issue

Tags: c#, installation, dll, uwp

I have UWP app that has reference to the Microsoft.Sqlserver.Types via Nuget and inside has
the code

```
var coords = new List<BasicGeoposition>();
var point = SqlGeography.Point(wDitsrLoaderLat, wDitsrLoaderLng, 4326);
var poly = point.BufferWithTolerance(radiusInMeter, 0.01, true);
for (int i = 1; i <= poly.STNumPoints(); i++)
{
   var currentPoint = poly.STPointN(i);
   coords.Add(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = currentPoint.Lat.Value, Longitude = currentPoint.Long.Value });
}
```

Under development environment it works fine but after runing the UWP app on the client's computer MS Windows 10 this error appears

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL
> 'SqlServerSpatial140.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified
> module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GLNativeMethods.GeodeticAngleExtent(GeoMarshalData
> g, Double eccentricity, Double& result)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GLNativeMethods.GeodeticAngleExtent(GeoData
> g, Double eccentricity)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.EnvelopeAngle()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.BufferWithTolerance(Double
> distance, Double tolerance, Boolean relative)

I have verified that `microsoft.sqlserver.types.dll` exists under the installation folder

[image]

Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the asnwer
[Unable to load DLL 'SqlServerSpatial140.dll': The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42654893/unable-to-load-dll-sqlserverspatial140-dll-the-specified-module-could-not-be)

We have to include both DLLs from

```
.nuget\packages\microsoft.sqlserver.types\14.0.1016.290\nativeBinaries\x64\SqlServerSpatial140.dll

.nuget\packages\microsoft.sqlserver.types\14.0.1016.290\nativeBinaries\x64\msvcr120.dll
```

to the UWP app project and mark it to COPY ALWAYS.

That's it! )))