# Using DbGeography for geo location

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, geospatial

I have a scenario in which I need to calculate the distance between to addresses. I've seen numerous examples using `DbGeography` in the `System.Data.Entity` namespace, however I seem to run my head against the wall since my application cannot load `SqlServerSpatial110.dll` library.

I've read several articles and SO's regarding this specific issue, but none of them seem to work for me, hence the reason for this SO, hoping to find some other angle to my specific scenario.

**Environment**

- I've added the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` library from NuGet.
- I've added the `SqlServerSpatial110.dll´ file from my folder:`Windows/System32`

I'm trying to calculate the distance like this:

```
var loc1 = DbGeography.FromText(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat, "POINT({0} {1})", someLatitude, someLongitude));
var loc2 = DbGeography.FromText(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat, "POINT({0} {1})", someLatitude, someLongitude));

var distance = loc1.Distance(loc2);
```

**Problem**
Whenever I try to run my application, and this code is run, I get an exception:

> Unable to load DLL SqlServerSpatial.dll : The specified module could not be found.

I've seen this error happen to other people, but I have yet to find a possible solution.

I suppose the exception is thrown because it cannot load the library (as it says so), but I can't figure WHY it cannot load the library. As mentioned, I took the `SqlServerSpatial110.dll` from my `Windows/System32` folder, as many people suggested this was were to find the correct DLL.

Any suggestions or possible fixed are much obliged.

*So far, I've been able to fix this issue using the `System.Device` namespace instead. This works a bit different, and I'm pretty sure this isn't driven in the database, but inside my application instead. I'd rather have this done in the database, as performance could be heavily decreased the more entries I get.*

Comment: Not related to your current problem, but be aware that you're passing lat/long the wrong way around. `POINT(<long> <lat>)` is the text you need to build

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to load DLL 'SqlServerSpatial.dll'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868326/unable-to-load-dll-sqlserverspatial-dll)

Comment: Make sure you uncheck the "prefer 32 bit" default option in Visual Studio Project Properties. Apparently the DLL only works in 64 bit. You may also need the 64 bit of IIS Express.