# Server Error that Unable to load DLL 'SqlServerSpatial110.dll'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller, dll

locally its working  fine. When i am going to deployed to Plesk server after that time trying to post(insert)into sql server its show me Internal server error or

Unable to load DLL 'SqlServerSpatial110.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

**Description:** 
An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:**

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'SqlServerSpatial110.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

**Source Error:**

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

> [DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'SqlServerSpatial110.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)]
>      Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GLNativeMethods.SetClrFeatureSwitchMap(Int32 clrFeatureSwitchMap) +0
>      Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.IsValidExpensive() +104
>      Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.Construct(GeoData g, Int32 srid) +180
>      Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.GeometryFromText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars text, Int32 srid) +224
>      Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.STGeomFromText(SqlChars geometryTaggedText, Int32 srid) +20
>      Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.Parse(SqlString s) +185

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868326/unable-to-load-dll-sqlserverspatial-dll

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to load DLL 'SqlServerSpatial.dll'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868326/unable-to-load-dll-sqlserverspatial-dll)