# Getting Errors Trying to Load SqlServerSpatial140.dll

Tags: sql-server, sqlgeography

I am using SqlGeography in a project that was working but now is not.  The only thing that has changed that I can think of is that Windows 10 did an update to my PC but I am unsure that that is the source of the problem.

I used NuGet to remove and then re-add the reference to SqlServer140.dll and got this message:

> Errors were detected when processing \packages\microsoft.sqlserver.types. 14.0.1016.290\nativebinaries\x64\SQLSERVERPARTIAL140.dll.    Please make sure that the file eis accesible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.

I used [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868326/unable-to-load-dll-sqlserverspatial-dll) to work on this problem.  I downloaded Dependency Walker and ran it against SqlServerSpastial140.dll and got this error message:

> Errors were detected when processing that .  See the log window for details.

Unfortunately, the help file for Dependency Walker is not included in the download (I downloaded both form its home page and also a link at Microsoft - the help was missing from both) so I do not know how to read the result.  Here is an image of the result:
[image]

Assuming the "log window" is the one at the very bottom, it is not helpful.  What do I have to do to restore the SqlGeography functionality.  I've also tried other suggestions from the link mentioned above but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to go to this file location below and copy the SqlServerSpatial140.dll to my project bin folder.

C:\Users<user>.nuget\packages\microsoft.sqlserver.types\14.0.1016.290\nativeBinaries\x64