# Entity Framework 6 - An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-6

I've published my application to my server (iis7.5 windows server 2008 R2, asp.net4). I tried to set build to x86, x64, any cpu and it doesn't worked. I tried to allow 32bit applications through IIS and still the same result.

The error occurred only when I try to get some data from database using entity framework 6.0.2. Everything working when I loading a static MCV page (without database calls).

This is my error:
[image: This is my error]

Your help will be very appreciated

Comment: 33 bit applications? Rad!

Comment: I had similar issues when SQL Server tried to load 32bit DLLs instead of 64bit ones - something like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265845/unable-to-load-sqlserverspatial-dll

Comment: According to this url (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26728) there are more than 30 installment options.
What should I select?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't worked