# SqlServer Spatial DataReader.GetFieldType returned null

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, geospatial

I have a .net4.5 web application project that uses SQL server spatial datatype.

Works perfectly locally on development machine, but when deployed to application server I get the following error when trying to run queries on table with spatial data:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: DataReader.GetFieldType(5) returned null.
```

I found out that if SQLServer is not installed on the server, there is no support for spatial data types.

Therefore I installed the nuget package to my project:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
```

This added references to Microsoft.SqlServer.Types and created a SqlServerTypes folder that contained some dlls.

After re-deploying the project to the server, it still doesn't work (same error).

The instructions from the nuget package say that I must add the following line to the applciaion_start event:

```
SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

I have tried doing this but I am getting squiggly blue line under SqlServerTypes with the error "SqlServerTypes is not declared" in Visual Studio.

I have tried adding

```
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
```

but there is no SqlServerTypes namespace or class.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265845/unable-to-load-sqlserverspatial-dll

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nuget package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types is only for c# projects.

You can modify the class to be compatible with vb.net projects.

Install support into your project using:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
```

Locate the following file:

```
/SqlServerTypes/Loader.cs
```

Convert the code in Loader.cs to vb (you can do this with an online converter) and save the file as: Loader.vb

Now you will be able to access the **SqlServerTypes** namespace from your project.

Comment: This got me in the right direction; however I needed to add a reference to the types in my `app.config` file detailed in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44819952/1521562