# Spatial types and functions are not available for this provider because the assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types'

Tags: .net, entity-framework, nuget, nuget-package, visual-studio-2017

Windows recently blue screens and re-installed itself. As a result I had to reinstall all my development tooling. I had VS 2015 and now am using VS 2017

I got this error when trying to run a **.NET 4.6** Web App that was previously working

> Spatial types and functions are not available for this provider
>   because the assembly `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` version 10 or higher
>   could not be found.

The solution I found online is to run

```
Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
```

The Package contains instructions:
ASP.NET applications For ASP.NET applications, add the following line of code to the `Application_Start` method in `Global.asax.cs`: `SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(Server.MapPath("~/bin"));`

I tried to add that line to my `Global.asax.vb` (this is vb.net project)
Intellisense underlines S`qlServerTypes` in red and does not offer a using statement as a suggestion.

What namespace is `SqlServerTypes` under? If that is the top `Namespace` then why would it not recognize it after installing the nuget package?

EDIT - None of the solutions I found online worked for me. I tried installing the SQL 2016 CLR Types on my machine and also the suggested nuget package and converted the .cs to .vb

I did solve the problem by installing this Nuget package I found
Install-Package HashFoo.SqlServer.SpatialTypes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SqlServer Spatial DataReader.GetFieldType returned null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23565095/sqlserver-spatial-datareader-getfieldtype-returned-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install-Package HashFoo.SqlServer.SpatialTypes fixed it for me.