# Sqlserverspatial160.DLL is missing while building docker image

Tags: c#, .net, docker, geospatial

I’m new to C# and .Net. I’m facing a similar issue as mentioned here: [Unable to load SqlServerSpatial.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265845/unable-to-load-sqlserverspatial-dll).

I have these unit tests which works fine locally, but when I add these tests while building the docker image, I see this error. I checked the build folder and it contains Microsoft.sqlserver.types dll of required version. What should I do to resolve this issue? Any insights on this will be greatly appreciated.